# ZipFile.getEntry causing java aplication to hang

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have this application that is hanging with no apparent reason. I performed a thread dump in order to check what is being done by the application while on that state and found out almost all my HTTP threads were stuck on `ZipFile.getEntry` as follows:

```
"http-bio-8010-exec-217" #1059431 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1b99933000 nid=0x12ac waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f1b01841000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:308)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007100a9dd8> (a java.util.jar.JarFile)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1005)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:212)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:265)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getBootstrapResource(ClassLoader.java:1264)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1093)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1091)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResource(ClassLoader.java:1226)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1329)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.tailor(AccessorInjector.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:68)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:388)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.<init>(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor53.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at foo.bar.app.core.base.Response.format(ServiceResponse.java:121)
    at foo.bar.app.bind.response.Response.serialize(BaseQueryInfoResponse.java:156)
    at foo.bar.app.core.Unicity.update(Idempotency.java:377)
    at foo.bar.app.core.Unicity.process(Idempotency.java:274)
    at foo.bar.app.core.dispatcher.RequestDispatcher.dispatch(RequestDispatcher.java:138)
    at foo.bar.app.web.controller.MainController.dispatch(MainController.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    - locked <0x0000000756283100> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007562831d0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

The thread blocking all others on ZipFile.getEntry was:

```
"http-bio-8010-exec-40" #932346 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1b2c0cf000 nid=0x1ae0 runnable [0x00007f1b0d94f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.freeEntry(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:313)
    - locked <0x00000007100a9dd8> (a java.util.jar.JarFile)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1005)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:212)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:265)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getBootstrapResource(ClassLoader.java:1264)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1093)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1091)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResource(ClassLoader.java:1226)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1329)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.tailor(AccessorInjector.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:68)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:388)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.<init>(TransducedAccessor.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.<init>(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor53.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor150.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor59.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at foo.bar.app.core.base.Response.format(ServiceResponse.java:121)
    at foo.bar.app.bind.response.Response.serialize(BaseQueryInfoResponse.java:156)
    at foo.bar.app.core.Unicity.update(Idempotency.java:377)
    at foo.bar.app.core.Unicity.process(Idempotency.java:274)
    at foo.bar.app.core.dispatcher.RequestDispatcher.dispatch(RequestDispatcher.java:138)
    at foo.bar.app.web.controller.MainController.dispatch(MainController.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    - locked <0x0000000752b0b840> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x0000000749f0d580> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

As it could be seen there is one thread blocking others, but what causes could lead to freeEntry stuck like that?

Comment: Judging by OpenJDK code there is locking in native code as well in the "freeEntry" (it might not be relevant to Oracle one, but something similar happens there potentially [here is the link](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/jdk/src/share/native/java/util/zip/zip_util.c#1095)). Could you please add a `pstack` ([here is the link](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pstack1.html)) output for the same condition to see what's the problem in native code?

Comment: Maybe someone manually overwrote the jar file while the application was loading a class from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to Linux Futex_Wait issue described [here](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/05/redhat-futex).

It took a while to figure it out because the problem wasn't reproducible and popped up once in a while, presenting different symptoms, from out of memories due to finalizer queue pile up to Tomcat thread exhaustion waiting for class loading.

Comment: I'm facing this issue after migrating a SpringBoot app to Docker... Do you recall what I should look at when trying to solve this problem? Details about the bug at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1284

Comment: I could see that when extracting a thread dump with native stack included. That gave me the required hint to find out the problem.